# Is there accepted notation for the pushforward measure that doesn't mention $\mathbf{P}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$ denote a probability space, $(S,\mathcal{M})$ denote a measurable space, and $X : (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P}) \rightarrow (S,\mathcal{M})$ denote a measurable function (thought of as a random variable). Then there is a pushforward measure induced on $(S,\mathcal{M})$ (thought of as the probability distribution of $X$), which we could denote $X_*(\mathbf{P}),$ following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward).

However, I like to imagine that $X$ "knows" that its domain is the whole probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P}).$ Hence $X$ is "aware of" the probability measure on its domain, and hence we shouldn't have to mention $\mathbf{P}$ in the notation for the pushforward. This coincides better with how I like to write and talk: I will usually just speak of the "probability distribution" of $X$, without mentioning $\mathbf{P}$ at all.

> **Question.** Is there accepted notation for the pushforward measure that doesn't mention $\mathbf{P}$? Something like $\mathrm{distr}(X)$ or $\mathbf{D}(X)$, for example.

Comment: It's been a while since I've thought about these things, but I think there's some confusion with the way you've set things up. The probability space and the measure on that space are different objects, but you seem to conflate them. You don't push forward the space, you push forward the measure on that space. And $X$ may "know" its domain, but it doesn't "know" the measure on that domain.

Comment: Also, usually $\mathcal M$ is reserved for the collection of measurable sets on space, not the space itself.

Comment: @Potato, I intentionally conflate them here because IMO there is no danger in this particular context.

Comment: But the question you're asking seems to arise exactly from the kind of confusion that comes from conflating them. It's simply not true that $X$, defined as a function, contains any information about the measure on its domain.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I agree with @Potato that it is nonstandard notation, and looks weird.

Comment: @Potato, you're limiting your imagination unnecessarily. We're allowed to equip $X$ with any additional information we like. This is quite important in category theory, where for example a morphism between groups would be understood to have groups for its domain and codomain, not sets.

Comment: @NateEldredge, can you recommend a less weird-looking notation? Its just that I can't stand the whole ordered triple thing, it just kills readability (for me).

Comment: A function is a set of ordered pairs satisfying a certain condition. If I just hand you $X$ as a set of ordered pairs and tell you that it's a measurable function between two measure spaces, you cannot in general recover either measure uniquely.

Comment: @Potato: It's quite common in probability books/papers to "suppress" the underlying probability space.  That's what's happening here: the pushforward measure depends on $X$ and also implicitly on the underlying measure $P$, but we often omit the underlying measure from our notation.  For instance, every time we say "almost surely", we are implicitly using the measure $P$, but we don't say so unless it's necessary to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @Potato, once again, let me just re-empahsize that you're limiting yourself unnecessarily. When Bourbaki innovated the notion of a [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain), many mathematicians objected to the notion. But since it improved readability and clarity, except possibly in the context of ZFC, codomains were eventually accepted, except possibly in the context of ZFC. Eventually, category theory was discovered, at which point the naturalness of codomains was finally formalized. The point is this: just like Bourbaki decided that their functions have more data, so too can we.

Comment: I'm a working probabilist, and I have to tell you that the ordered triple notation $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is absolutely universal in this field - *anything* else looks weird.  I'm sorry you don't like it!

Comment: @goblin With all due respect, you are not Bourbaki.

Comment: @Potato, now you're just being silly. This has nothing to do with authority - which, by the way, I don't believe in; I do not accept that Bourbaki or anyone else in mathematics have *any* authority, except over their own writing - rather, it has everything to do with what's logically possible.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sure. What I'm objecting to is what looks to me like a philosophical confusion brought about by a poor choice of notation.

Comment: @NateEldredge, well, thanks for your honesty.

Comment: @goblin That was mostly in jest. But really, you realize that (as far as I know) no definition of "measurable function" in common use requires that function to have the probability measure of its domain as a datum? The definition you have in mind seems to be your invention. Which is fine, I suppose, but it would probably be worth noting in questions like these that you're doing slightly nonstandard mathematics. Otherwise, it looks like you're just confused!

Comment: @Potato, I've standardized it a bit, in light of Nate's comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so that everyone knows what we are talking about here, let me rephrase in more familiar notation.

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space, and $(M, \mathcal{M})$ is a measurable space.  If $X : \Omega \to M$ is a random variable (i.e. a $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{M})$-measurable function), it induces a pushforward measure on $(M, \mathcal{M})$, which we might denote as $\mu$, defined by $\mu(A) = P(X^{-1}(A))$.

The measure $\mu$ is sometimes called the **distribution** or **law** of $X$, and as such I've often seen it denoted by $$\operatorname{Law}(X)$$ or $\operatorname{law}(X)$.  See for instance Definition 1.10 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8010) by myself and collaborators, in which we use this notation.  We didn't invent it; I don't know who did, but it is quite common in the field, and I think it would be generally understood by probabilists.

For instance, if we had some other measure $\nu$ on $M$ laying around, we could write something like "$\operatorname{Law}(X) \ll \nu$" if it so happened that the one measure was absolutely continuous to the other.  In principle you could write something like "$(\operatorname{Law}(X))(B) = 2/3$" but in practice you would simply write "$P(X \in B) = 2/3$" instead.  If you plan to use the measure extensively, you should give it a name (e.g. "Let $\mu = \operatorname{Law}(X)$").

As Potato  correctly points out, this notation makes it look like the measure only depends on $X$, when of course it also depends on the underlying probability measure $P$.  But it is quite standard in probability theory to tacitly assume that everything in sight depends implicitly on the underlying probability space, and thus to suppress it from notation.  I guess one could take a categorical interpretation as goblin does, and say that the underlying probability space is "part of" the object $X$, but I don't think most probabilists think that way.

Answer (score 0):

Given a measureable $f:(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)\to(Y,\mathcal{N})$ (a measure space to a measurable space) one can define a measure $\nu=f_{*}\mu$ on $(Y,\mathcal{N})$ by
$$
\nu(B)=\mu(f^{-1}(B)).
$$
Both $f$ and $\mu$ are necessary to define it, so $f_{*}\mu$ seems like good notation to me.